# Why won't my php code redirect to any php page?

Tags: php

Here is my index page where i can successfully login but wont redirect to any page? just new been trying to get it to working.

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div style="height:50px;">
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="loginform">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login
                        <span class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> <a style="text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer; color:white;" id="signup">Sign up</a></span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <!-- Body For Login -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" id="logform">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" type="password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" id="loginbutton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> <span id="logtext">Login</span></button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                     <!-- Body For Login -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="signupform" style="display:none;">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Sign Up
                        <span class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> <a style="text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer; color:white;" id="login">Login</a></span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!-- Body for Sign up -->
                    <form role="form" id="signform">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="name" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="susername" id="susername" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="spassword" id="spassword" type="password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" id="signupbutton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> <span id="signtext">Sign Up</span></button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                     <!-- Body for Sign up -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myalert" style="display:none;">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <center><span id="alerttext"></span></center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i don't know why but just keep going back to index.page

```
<?php 
    include('conn.php');
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['logform'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);

        $query=$conn->query("select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'");

        if ($query->num_rows>0) {
            $row=$query->fetch_array();
            if ($row['level']=="admin") {
               $_SESSION['users']=$row['id']; 
               $_SESSION['level']=$row['level'];
               header('location: admin/index.php');
            }elseif ($row['level']=="agent") {
               $_SESSION['users']=$row['id']; 
               $_SESSION['level']=$row['level'];
               header('location: agent/index.php');
            }elseif ($row['level']=="user") {
               $_SESSION['users']=$row['id']; 
               $_SESSION['level']=$row['level'];
               header('location: agent/index.php');
            }else{
            ?>
                <span>Login Failed. User not Found.</span>
            <?php 
            }


            }


        }
```

Here is my login action form it working but will not redirect to any page that i set them i don't know why but im trying my best how to work around the problem

Here is my custom.js which tell the php what to do next

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //bind enter key to click button
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which == 13){
            if($('#loginform').is(":visible")){
                $("#loginbutton").click();
            }
            else if($('#signupform').is(":visible")){
                $("#signupbutton").click();
            }
        }
    });

    $('#signup').click(function(){
        $('#loginform').slideUp();
        $('#signupform').slideDown();
        $('#myalert').slideUp();
        $('#signform')[0].reset();
    });

    $('#login').click(function(){
        $('#loginform').slideDown();
        $('#signupform').slideUp();
        $('#myalert').slideUp();
        $('#logform')[0].reset();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#signupbutton', function(){
        if($('#susername').val()!='' && $('#spassword').val()!=''){
            $('#signtext').text('Signing up...');
            $('#myalert').slideUp();
            var signform = $('#signform').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'signup.php',
                data: signform,
                success:function(data){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#myalert').slideDown();
                    $('#alerttext').html(data);
                    $('#signtext').text('Sign up');
                    $('#signform')[0].reset();
                    }, 2000);
                } 
            });
        }
        else{
            alert('Please input both fields to Sign Up');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#loginbutton', function(){
        if($('#username').val()!='' && $('#password').val()!=''){
            $('#logtext').text('Logging in...');
            $('#myalert').slideUp();
            var logform = $('#logform').serialize();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'login.php',
                    data: logform,
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data==''){
                            $('#myalert').slideDown();
                            $('#alerttext').text('Login Successful. User Verified!');
                            $('#logtext').text('Login');
                            $('#logform')[0].reset();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                location.reload();
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#myalert').slideDown();
                            $('#alerttext').html(data);
                            $('#logtext').text('Login');
                            $('#logform')[0].reset();
                        }
                    } 
                });
            }, 2000);
        }
        else{
            alert('Please input both fields to Login');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `var_dump($_POST);` to see the data of your `$_POST` then you will realize that there's no `logform`.

Comment: logform is from my custom.js even tried doing username and password has not yet populated in the database even say successful.

Comment: You should test your script first by making it actually post via form submission instead of Ajax. Then once it’s working normally go back and attempt Ajax. Also, in the php that is accessed by Ajax, you should use a JavaScript redirect on success.

Comment: Thanks got it already working

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use**

```
<input type ="submit" id="loginbutton">
```

**instead of**

```
  <button type="button" id="loginbutton">
```

**to post your form.**

Comment: I believe you can have spaces in the attributes, its just messy looking.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
header('location: admin/index.php');
```

to

```
header('Location: agent/index.php');
```

it is an easy mistake to make

Comment: problems is wont redirect only at the login page keep saying successfully login even tried doing username and password that has not yet been populated still says successful login

Comment: I am almost certain lowercase will work vs uppercase `L`

Comment: yeah, I think the L can be lowercase but I know you should have it uppercase I have never tried a lowercase L if that does not work you must be redirecting to the wrong place is your PHP file in a subfolder

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the `method`and `action` in form tag. The method attribute specifies how to send form-data. When posting a form, it always good to have a method is `post`. As for action, a route or file location where action should perform.

So try this:

```
<form method="post" action="/{_action_filename_}.php">
```